# How do I get a big-picture feel for my database?

Tags: data, data-analysis, sql, databases

**Background:** I was just granted access to my company's SQL Server (MS SQL 2019 via Azure Data Studio). As I have not yet been assigned any specific projects I want start digging.

I've asked my DBA to send me any database diagrams available, to this point he hasn't located any.

**Question:** What sort of scripts can I run to better understand general table relations, primary/foreign keys, dependencies and overall database structure?

**What I've checked already:** As far as online resources go, the majority of what I've come across start with the steps to create a database / table and then go into exploratory analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Azure Data Studio is not capable of showing you the diagrams. You can download Dbeaver for free and then look at the ER Diagram tab. It will show you a graph of the Database, showing exactly what you are interested in - relations, keys, dependencies, structure.